# @input on component gives error: Property 'showingSingle' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

SO I have a angular 8 application.

And I have this in the component DossierCorrespondenceComponent:

```
  @Input() showingSingle = false;
```

So that I can use it in a other component(DossierCorrespondenceListComponent). But if I do this:

```
<div *ngIf="!showingSingle && correspondenceEntries && correspondenceEntries.length > 0;">
```

Then I will get this error:

```
Property 'showingSingle' does not exist on type 'DossierCorrespondenceListComponent'.
```

So how to fix this?

Thank you

html:

```
<div *ngIf="!showingSingle  && correspondenceEntries && correspondenceEntries.length > 0;">
  <div class="main-row main-row-dossier">
    <section class="data-entry">
      <h3 class="dossier-header">Algemeen</h3>
      <table class="dossier-table">
        <thead class="dossier-tableheader">
          <tr>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-one-fifth">Datum</th>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-four-fifths">Onderwerp</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dossier-tablebody">
          <tr class="dossier-correspondencerow" *ngFor="let entry of correspondenceEntries; let i = index" (click)="gotoItem(i, entry.type)">
            <td>{{ entry.date | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceListComponent implements OnInit {

  correspondenceEntries: DossierEntry[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

js:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  allCorrespondence: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input()
  correspondenceEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input()
  attachmentEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
 /*  allCorrespondence$: Observable<DossierEntry>;
  correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry>;
  attachmentEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry>; */
  message = '';
  emptyMessageCorrespondentie = 'Geen correspondentie.';
  errorMessageConnection = 'Er ging iets mis met de connectie. Probeer over enkele minuten nogmaals.';

  correspondenceLoaded = false;

  @Input() showingSingle = false;

  single: DossierEntry;

  constructor(
    private healthAPIService: HealthAPIService,
    private prevRouterService: PreviousRouteService,
    private dossierService: DossierService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('correspondence').subscribe(result => {
      this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
    }, msg => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
  }

  handleCorrespondenceLoad(result) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie;
      return;
    }
    this.allCorrespondence = result;
    this.attachmentEntries = [];
    this.correspondenceEntries = [];

    const groups = _.groupBy(result, 'type');
    groups.correspondence.push(result);
    groups.attachments.push(result);

  }

  gotoItem(index, type: string) {
    this.showingSingle = true;

    /*    _.mapValues(type, function(group, key) {
      return type === 'correspondence' ? _.groupBy(group, 'attachments') : group;
}); */

    const groupData = _.groupBy(type, item => {
      return _.get(item, 'correspondence', 'attachments');
    });

    switch (type) {
      case 'correspondence': {
        this.single = this.correspondenceEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      case 'attachments': {
        this.single = this.attachmentEntries[index];
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
    this.showingSingle = true;
  }

  goBack(event) {
    this.showingSingle = false;
  }
}
```

YOu mean in here:

```
<tbody class="dossier-tablebody">
          <tr class="dossier-correspondencerow" *ngFor="let entry of correspondenceEntries; let i = index" (click)="gotoItem(i, entry.type)">
            <td>{{ entry.date | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

So this is the html of DossierCorospondenceComponent:

```
<app [noTopBar]="true">
  <h2 class="dossier-page-header">Correspondentie</h2>

  <p class="data-entry" *ngIf="!allCorrespondence">{{ message }}</p>

  <app-is-loading *ngIf="!correspondenceLoaded" message="Correspondentie wordt geladen"></app-is-loading>


  <app-dossier-correspondence-list ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>

  <app-dossier-correspondence-item
    [item]="single"
    (goBack)="goBack($event)"
    *ngIf="showingSingle">
  </app-dossier-correspondence-item>
</app>
```

So I have it like this:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceListComponent implements OnInit {

  correspondenceEntries: DossierEntry[];

  @Input() showingSingle = false;  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

But what I have to put in here:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  allCorrespondence: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input()
  correspondenceEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input()
  attachmentEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
 /*  allCorrespondence$: Observable<DossierEntry>;
  correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry>;
  attachmentEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry>; */
  message = '';
  emptyMessageCorrespondentie = 'Geen correspondentie.';
  errorMessageConnection = 'Er ging iets mis met de connectie. Probeer over enkele minuten nogmaals.';

  correspondenceLoaded = false;

  @Input() showingSingle = false;

  single: DossierEntry;

  constructor(
    private healthAPIService: HealthAPIService,
    private prevRouterService: PreviousRouteService,
    private dossierService: DossierService
  ) {}
```

Because now it is a double property

Comment: my anwser updated

Comment: what is your intention, can you modify the js, html title to the real name of the file, I understood you want to display a list DCC, so you should add DCC in a loop inside DCLC

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with the html

Comment: as I understood, you should add `@Input showingSingle` into DCLC, so you can pass this value from DCC to DCLC

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: oke, and then this: showingSingle = false; in DCC

Comment: you now can pass the `showingSingle` value into DCLC from DCC like normal

Comment: Hi, but can you show in code how it will looks like now. Because now I dont know if I am doing it right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199675/discussion-between-tho-vo-and-mightycode-newton).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it said clear that `showingSingle` not existed in `DossierCorrespondenceListComponent`, you need to declare it inside `DossierCorrespondenceListComponent` to use it.

If you can, show us your code for `DossierCorrespondenceListComponent` and `DossierCorrespondenceComponent` to see what you want to achieve is better.

You may see document of Angular Input for more infos how to do it [Angular Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

**UPDATE 1**

To be short: DCLC => `DossierCorrespondenceListComponent` and DCC for `DossierCorrespondenceComponent`

I see you want to display a list of DCC component, the property `showingSingle` need to bypass a value from DCLC.

In your `ngFor` loop, add `showingSingle` into the loop like this

```
<div *ngFor="let c of list">
  <DCC [showingSingle]="c"></DCC>
</div>
```

A side note: You should use English instead of French for the name of component, and you are working with Germans

Comment: Hi, thank you. Eh, but what do you mean working with Germans? I am not working with Germans. Dutch people :)